# Rotation/moving camera using GLES20

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am creating an android application using GLES20.

I need to draw some 2d polygons and then i need to rotate and move scene using VOB.

I write polygon using **GLES20.glDrawArrays()** it's ok.

But how i can to move left/right/up/down and rotate camera without redrawing polygon?

UPD

GLES1 have gluLookAt(). but GLES2 havn't it.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple to implement look at yourself. You can use the following pseudocode as your starting point:

```
void LookAt(float r_t_matrix[4][4], Vector3f v_eye, Vector3f v_target, Vector3f v_up)
{
    Vector3f v_dir(v_target - v_eye);
    v_dir.Normalize();
    Vector3f v_right(v_dir.v_Cross(v_up));
    v_right.Normalize();
    v_up = v_right.v_Cross(v_dir);
    // calculate complete perpendicular coordinate frame

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++ i)
        r_t_matrix[i][0] = v_right[i];
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++ i)
        r_t_matrix[i][1] = v_up[i];
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++ i)
    r_t_matrix[i][2] = -v_dir[i];
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++ i) {
    r_t_matrix[i][3] = 0;
    r_t_matrix[3][i] = 0;
    }
    r_t_matrix[3][3] = 1;
    // copy it to matrix

    r_t_matrix.Translate(-v_eye.x, -v_eye.y, -v_eye.z);
    // apply translation
}
```

Alternately, you can use library, such as glm, which implements this functionality.

In Java, you can use [android.opengl.matrix.setLookAtM](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/Matrix.html#setLookAtM%28float%5B%5D,%20int,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29). That would be used as follows:

```
float[] matrix = new float[16];
setLookAtM(matrix, 0, eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, centerX, centerY, centerZ, upX, upY, upZ);
```

Where eye is camera position, center is target position and up is the up vector (usually (0, 1, 0) will do). You then take this matrix and draw the scene with it. You might want to multiply it with your model matrix and projection (if other than orthogonal).